# SQL/HANA query assigning incremental number per X unique values without using stored procedure

Tags: sql, hana

Currently I'm struggling trying to write a select query to achieve the following result:

[image]

I have documents, each document has an address.
Now I want a third column that will assign a unique number for every X unique adresses found in the result list. In the example I have used X = 3.

There are a total of 7 unique adresses. Which means we need 3 unique numbers.
1 = (adres A,B,C) , 2 = (adres D,E,F), 3= (adres G).

PS. I have already worked out this logic in a stored procedure, but because of technical limitations that I can't go into detail about this has to be done using a SELECT query if possible. If this is not possible we will have to find another workaround.

I was hoping you could point me in the right direction for which HANA SQL syntax to use to achieve this.. I've been looking into ROW_NUMBER and DENSE_RANK but without success.

Comment: In order for your question to make sense, you need a column that specifies the ordering.  Is that the first column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your question to make sense, you need an ordering column.  This answer assumes that `document` orders the rows.

You want to assign the group based on the minimum `document` of each address (and then do arithmetic).  You can get this with two levels of window functions:

```
select t.*,
       ceil(dense_rank() over (order by min_document) / 3.0) as incremental_number
from (select t.*,
             min(document) over (partition by address) as min_document
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks this solved it! The query:
SELECT
*
, CEILING(CAST(DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tbl."Address") / 2 AS DECIMAL(19,6))) AS "Wave"
FROM
(
      SELECT '1' AS "DocEntry", 'A' AS "Address" FROM DUMMY
      UNION
      SELECT '2' AS "DocEntry", 'D' AS "Address" FROM DUMMY
      UNION
      SELECT '3' AS "DocEntry", 'B' AS "Address" FROM DUMMY
      UNION
      SELECT '4' AS "DocEntry", 'C' AS "Address" FROM DUMMY
      UNION
      SELECT '5' AS "DocEntry", 'B' AS "Address" FROM DUMMY  
      UNION
      SELECT '5' AS "DocEntry", 'E' AS "Address" FROM DUMMY       
) tbl

Comment: @Jimmy . . . If this answers your question, you can accept it.